# how to add color on ListView when i Click in JqueryMobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

hi i Tried add color on ListView When i Click
i Have List View like :-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>


#aks:active {
    content: url('http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eb00eb/fff');
}

</style>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
<ul id="mylist" data-role="listview"  data-split-theme="c">

<li><a  id="aks" href="audi.html">mahindra Scorpio</a></li>
<li><a href="audi.html">BMW</a></li>
<li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
<li><a href="audi.html">BenZ</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

This code will Display listView but now i want When i click List Item(When I Click BMW) it should change to  Green color and when click released it should get back to original color.

Please Give me any Idea

Comment: What have you tried? Any JS code? Cause we won't tell you how to learn javascript from the scratch..

Comment: @gulty i changed my code,used CSS style but i want to change color instead of image

Comment: What does 'when the click is released' means for you? On mouse button down it's going to change the color to green and releasing the mouse (button up) you want to change the color to change back to normal? you can't use css for that. u have to check for the jquery on click function better said: mouseup() and mousedown(). Try to impelemt it (u can change the color using $(this) to select the clicked element) and update your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with the green background (plus darker green on hover if you like):

```
.activeLI .ui-btn {
    background-color: #CFF09E !important;
}
.activeLI .ui-btn:hover {
    background-color: #A8DBA8 !important;
}
```

Then handle the click event of the LI and simply toggle the class:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("#mylist").on("click", "li", function(){        
        $(this).toggleClass("activeLI");
    });    
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/QFRqL/)**

**NOTE:** If you are using jQM 1.3 instead of the latest,

```
.activeLI {
    background-color: #CFF09E !important;
    background-image: none;
}
```

The background is applied directly to the LI and the background-image is used for gradients.

> **[jQM 1.3 DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/QFRqL/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

you should to add that

```
$("#mylist").find("li").removeClass("activeLI");
```

to remove all class and disable the last background